# Fibrant replacement functor

Tags: category-theory, functors, model-categories

In the snippet below (taken from Hovey's MC book) why is $$X\mapsto QX$$ but then the direction is **reversed**:$$QX\to X$$?

Also, I would like to understand in that paragraph how $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are used to get these
replacement functors: are they **both** used for cofibrant replacement functor, say ?
[image]

Comment: This is just an application of the functorial factorization axiom.

Comment: Also, the question seems to be more about **co**fibrant replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functorial factorization axiom asserts that every map factors by a cofibration followed by an acyclic (trivial) fibration (and you can also scoot the "trivial" part over to the cofibration factor).  Given the map $\varnothing \to X$, which always exists as $\varnothing$ is initial, we apply this axiom to get a factorization
$$
\varnothing \to QX \to X
$$
where the first is a cofibration and the second a trivial fibration.  This is your map $QX \to X$.  **The process of doing this,** however, is a functor that acts as $X \mapsto QX$.  That this is a functor is the "functorial" in functorial factorization.  This does not mean there is a map $X \to QX$. In other words, cofibrant replacement gives a functor $Q$ with $Q(X)=QX$.  He simply wrote this as $X \mapsto QX$ (and not $X \to QX$, which would mean something different and incorrect).

Comment: Just to be precise, does he use in the situation in your answer **both** or just **one** out of $\alpha$ and $\beta$; which one ?

Comment: If you read Axiom 4 on page 3 (of my original copy from years ago), doing this requires both $\alpha$ and $\beta$.